# Pandas mask with composite expression behaviour

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

this question was previously asked (and then deleted) by an user, I was looking to find a solution so I could give out an answer when the question disappeared and I, moreover, can't seem to make sense of pandas' behaviour so I would appreciate some clarity, the original question stated something along the lines of:

> How can I replace every negative value except those in a given list with NaN in a Pandas dataframe?

my setup to reproduce the scenario is the following:

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : [x for x in range(4)],
    'B' : [x for x in range(-2, 2)]
})
```

this should technically only be an issue of correctly passing a boolean expression to pd.where, my attemped solution looks like:

```python
df[df >= 0 | df.isin([-2])]
```

which produces:

| index | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | NaN |
| 1 | 1 | NaN |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |

which also cancels the number in the list!

moreover if I mask the dataframe with each of the two conditions I get the correct behavior:

### with `df[df >= 0]` (identical to the compound result)

| index | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | NaN |
| 1 | 1 | NaN |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |

### with `df[df.isin([-2])]` (identical to the compound result)

| index | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NaN | -2.0 |
| 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | NaN | NaN |

So it seems like I am

1. Running into some undefined behaviour as a result of performing logic on NaN values
2. I have got something wrong

Anyone can clarify this situation to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Solution

```
df[(df >= 0) | (df.isin([-2]))]
```

##### Explanation

In python, bitwise OR, `|`, has a higher operator precedence than comparison operators like `>=`: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

When filtering a pandas DataFrame on multiple boolean conditions, you need to enclose each condition in parentheses. More from the [boolean indexing section of the pandas user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

> Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the
> data. The operators are: `|` for `or`, `&` for `and`, and `~` for `not`. These
> **must** be grouped by using parentheses, since by default Python will
> evaluate an expression such as `df['A'] > 2 & df['B'] < 3` as `df['A'] > (2 & df['B']) < 3`, while the desired evaluation order is `(df['A'] > 2) & (df['B'] < 3)`.